# Email and log exceptions from an Azure Function

Tags: azure, exception, azure-functions

I have an Azure function and I wrapped the logic in a try catch block.
I can log the exception to Azure, but I want save and then send the details of the exception to an email address. I see I can use [Elmah.io](https://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-azure-functions/) but I have to pay a monthly subscription.

Doesn't Azure have a simple way to log the data and then send me an email?

Something like this

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Info($"Points Event Error: " + ex.Message);
    // send me email with details
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most Azure Function-ish way to do this would be to use [Azure Functions SendGrid ouput binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid).

You can follow the examples from that article, but instead of `out` parameter use `ICollector` / `IAsyncCollector` because you only need to send e-mails conditionally.

I believe Send Grid has a free tier available for low usage scenarios.

Comment: hey thanks. I'm already using sendgrid in my functions. What's the best way to wrap up the exception details and just send them via sendgrid?

Comment: @user1186050 Assign `ex.ToString()` to email body? :) The rest is up to how fancy you want it to look I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking to leverage SendGrid to send you emails on Exceptions directly from your Function you could consider leveraging [Functions' Application Insights integration](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights). This will give you additional benefits (performance tracking, history of events, trace logging) in addition to being able to [set Alerts based on Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-alerts) in Application Insights itself. It also means your monitoring / alerting isn't baked into your business logic in your Function.

Application Insights has a free tier that should suffice for most use cases.

Comment: You should explain that with app insights you can configure alert that will send email if something goes wrong ??

Comment: Thanks. Added a link to the docs page that covers how to setup Alerts.

Comment: Can you actually insert the exception details in the message? I've been able to setup alerts that let me know exceptions happened, but not the details (like message, stack trace, etc.), I have to search app insights to find them.